# GCC 4.8.1 in Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I was trying to compile and install gcc 4.8.1 in my cygwin (following this tutorial, http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC), but apparently I got stuck in a bump and maybe some of you could point me in the right direction. 
After running make the compilation stops at the following point:

```
Making all in include
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include'
mkdir -p ./i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch
mkdir -p ./i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch
/usr/local/contrib/build/./gcc/xgcc -shared-libgcc -B/usr/local/contrib/build/./contrib/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h \
-o i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2ggnu++0x.gch
/usr/local/contrib/build/./gcc/xgcc -shared-libgcc -B/usr/local/contrib/build/./gcc -nostdinc++ -L/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/src -L/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -B/usr/local/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ -B/usr/local/i686-pc-cygwin/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/i686-pc-cygwin/include -isystem /usr/local/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-include    -x c++-header -nostdinc++ -g -O2 -I/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin -I/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include -I/usr/local/contrib/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++ -O2 -g /usr/local/contrib/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h -o i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2g.gch
In file included from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr.h:148:0,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/string:52,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bitset:47,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:65:
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h: In function ‘int __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)’:
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: error: types may not be defined in casts
   if (TlsSetValue (__key, CONST_CAST2(void *, const void *, __ptr)) != 0)
                           ^
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘__gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::._333(const void*&)’
   if (TlsSetValue (__key, CONST_CAST2(void *, const void *, __ptr)) != 0)
                           ^
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()
   if (TlsSetValue (__key, CONST_CAST2(void *, const void *, __ptr)) != 0)
                           ^
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::<constructor>(const __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>&)
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const void*’ to ‘const __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>&’
In file included from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr.h:148:0,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/ios:42,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/istream:38,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/complex:45,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/local/contrib/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h:52:
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h: In function ‘int __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)’:
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: error: types may not be defined in casts
   if (TlsSetValue (__key, CONST_CAST2(void *, const void *, __ptr)) != 0)
                           ^
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘__gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::._338(const void*&)’
   if (TlsSetValue (__key, CONST_CAST2(void *, const void *, __ptr)) != 0)
                           ^
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::<constructor>()
   if (TlsSetValue (__key, CONST_CAST2(void *, const void *, __ptr)) != 0)
                           ^
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: constexpr __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::<constructor>(const __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>&)
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const void*’ to ‘const __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>&’
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note: constexpr __gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>::<constructor>(__gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>&&)
/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-pc-cygwin/bits/gthr-default.h:628:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const void*’ to ‘__gthread_setspecific(__gthread_key_t, const void*)::<anonymous union>&&’
Makefile:1569: recipe for target `i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2g.gch' failed
make[5]: *** [i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2g.gch] Error 1
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1564: recipe for target `i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2ggnu++0x.gch' failed
make[5]: *** [i686-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2ggnu++0x.gch] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include'
Makefile:480: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3'
Makefile:386: recipe for target `all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/build/i686-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3'
Makefile:12844: recipe for target `all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/build'
Makefile:16819: recipe for target `stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/contrib/build'
Makefile:883: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance,
Swatchpuppy

Comment: Cygwin's gcc packages contain a number of patches, so we do not recommend following those directions.  4.7.3 will be made available in a matter of days; you're best off waiting for that instead.